# How do I translate X to the 25th power into something php understands?

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to code 10 to the 25th power times a variable.
I have tried `X*(X^25)` but this does not return the correct value.
If it matters, this is the formula to find inflation, so the actual formula I'm using is:

```
X*(1.01^25)
```

- `X` is equal to the amount of money being calculated
- `1.01` is equal to 1% inflation
- `25` is equal to the number of years, which needs to be 25 in this case

Comment: Works, thank you for the answers!!

Comment: please upvote & accept the answer if you think they're useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use pow() function:

```
$x = 10;    
echo pow($x, 25); //(base, exponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the [pow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) command.

```
pow($number, $exponent)
```